# Authoring Map Journals Offline?

Tags: arcgis-online, story-map

Is there any way to use a [map journal](http://storymaps.arcgis.com/en/app-list/map-journal/) offline? That is assume all resources are local, like maps on an internal server and images hosted on the local pc.

I've downloaded the developer code of the Map Journals and been playing around for a while, but really, there is no way to alter the code of the actual Map Journal content outside of on ArcGIS Online.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this in theory. The only things that are requested from ArcGIS Online are the webmap and app json. So you could play around with the code to point to two files with the webmap and app json. Then you would alter the webmap and app json so that it only references offline resources (i.e. local basemaps and feature services).

The easiest way to replicate the feature service would be to create your feature service in ArcGIS Online, and download the file geodatabase. Then look at this in ArcMap and publish to your own server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use ArcGIS Online for Story Maps when I have similar requirements to what you describe.

Instead I use ArcGIS for Desktop and I have developed an eLearning video tutorial bundle that shows the techniques that I have put together for [Family HiStory Mapping](http://discoverspatial.com/courses/family-history-maps-bundle).

The key parts are a Python AddIn, File Geodatabase Attachments and HTML Popups.